# Accessing country_code of a tweet using tweepy raises "AttributeError from None"

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to write code to print the country code of all tweets that match a search query. I have tried to follow tweepy examples as well as twitter's documentation and examples on the internet, but I have not been able to find the way to do it. I have academic research access to the API, and this is my code (the query is a toy example):

```
import tweepy


bt = "..."

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bt)

query = 'hello has:geo -is:retweet'

response = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['geo'], place_fields=['country_code'],
                                  expansions=['geo.place_id'], max_results=10)

tweets = response.data
includes = response.includes
places = includes["places"]
places = {p["id"]: p for p in places}

for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.id)
    print(tweet.text)
    print(" country:    ", tweet.country_code)
```

I get the following error:

```
line 67, in <module>
    print(" country:    ", tweet.country_code)
  File "mypath", line 35, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError from None
AttributeError
```

I have tried adding this `if` statement I found in another question:

```
if tweet.place is not None:
    print(" country:    ",tweet.country_code)
else:
    print("Place not found")
```

But it raises the same error, but this time on the `if` statement line. I have tried printing the `tweet.geo` field but all it does is print the place id, which is not what I want.

I have seen many responses about how to filter by country. But this is for a linguistics research on the use of specifc structures around the world, so I need to get all of its uses and information on the country where the tweet was posted from.

How can I get the country code?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The error persists. I have also tried checking if tweet.country_code is None and i yields the same results. The problem here is that I don't understand where country_code is exactly, so I don't unerstand what should I b checking. I have tried with th documentation for days, but it is with a different language for the requests that I don't understand.

Comment: What's the output of `print(repr(tweet))`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Results of ten tweets are to lon, I will post just the first ones:
<Tweet id=1625088395528794113 text='Hello. The lovely spring night>
<Tweet id=1625088362401988610 text='@NIRA_Ug Hello @NIRA_Ug I lost my ID last month and I would love to make a replacement,what are the steps and requirements?'>
<Tweet id=1625088312963919872 text='@Poojara70078485 Hello '>
<Tweet id=1625088280176852992 text="Hello I just called to wish you a Valentine's day abeg no ask me money o.">
<Tweet id=1625088089046614016 text='@atiku Hello'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find a solution tanks to @mkrieger1 's help.

```
response = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['geo'],
                                    place_fields=['country_code'],
                                    expansions=['geo.place_id'], max_results=10)

tweets = response.data
includes = response.includes
places = includes["places"]
places = {p["id"]: p for p in places}

for tweet in tweets:
    try:
        print(tweet.text, "     ", places[tweet.geo["place_id"]]["country_code"], "\n")
    except:
        print("Country not found")
```

This solution does still yield tweets for which the country information is not set. The filter is applied in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v2_models.html, [`country_code`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v2_models.html#tweepy.Place.country_code) is not an attribute of a [`Tweet`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v2_models.html#tweepy.Tweet) object, but of a [`Place`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v2_models.html#tweepy.Place) object.

`Tweet` objects can have a `place` attribute, I presume it will be a `Place` instance as "child object".

So you would have to use `tweet.place.country_code`.

The `if` statement you mentioned hints at this but maybe you misinterpreted what you found.

It should be

```
if tweet.place is not None:
    print(" country:    ", tweet.place.country_code)
```

so that you first check if `tweet.place` exists, and only then access the `country_code` attribute of `tweet.place` (not of `tweet`).

Comment: I applied those changes and still got the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TwitterSearch.py", line 67, in <module>
    if tweet.place is not None:
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\tweepy\mixins.py", line 35, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError from None
AttributeError

Comment: You passed `tweet_fields=['geo']`, maybe it's called `.geo` and not `.place`? Or you should have used `tweet_fields=['place']`?

Comment: If I replace 'place' with 'geo' in 'tweet_fields" I get an error saying that is not a correct field (it is too long to copy in a comment).

If instead I use '.geo' instead of '.place' I get the following error. I have also applied the change to the 'if' statement:
line 68, in <module>
    print(" country:    ",tweet.geo.country_code)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'country_code'

Comment: I have tried checking directly if tweet.place.country_code and I get the same error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TwitterSearch.py", line 67, in <module>
    if tweet.place.country_code is not None:
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\tweepy\mixins.py", line 35, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError from None
AttributeError`
That makes e think it may be a problem with how I check that it is not None? @mkrieger1

Comment: Oh, so `.geo` does exist and is a dictionary. What's in it?

Comment: Also, I'm also not sure what is supposed to happen if a tweet isn't tagged with a place - is the `.place` attribute supposed to exist but is `None`, or does the attribute not exist at all? Maybe instead of checking for `None` you need to catch the `AttributeError` and move on to the next tweet.

Comment: According to the documentation: `Contains place details in GeoJSON format.

"geo": {
     "type": "Feature",
     "bbox": [
           -74.026675,
           40.683935,
           -73.910408,
           40.877483
      ],
      "properties": {}
   }`

Comment: That did avoid the error! However, I am unsure of how to access country_code as it now skips all tweets.

Comment: I made some changes, so the code is now as follows:
`response = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['geo'], place_fields=['country_code'],expansions=['geo.place_id'], max_results=10)

tweets = response.data
includes = response.includes
places = {p["id"]: p for p in includes['places']}
print(places)`
Which does print the default values of the `place` object. However, it does not have the one I added, 'country_code', among them. Eventhough I added what I needed, from my understanding of the documentation. @mkrieger1

Comment: I finally did it! Thank you for your help! How should I post the solution?

Comment: Write an answer!